# Phoenix Driver ClassNotFound in Spark3 Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, apache-phoenix, spark3

I am migrating the existing spark streaming application from spark2.3 to spark3.1.1. I have updated below-mentioned spark dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

And have added phoenix dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2-cdh5.11.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>phoenix-spark</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2-cdh5.11.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

While running spark job I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver`. The same code used to run with spark2.3 but now its not with spark3.1.1.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
```

Can someone please help me to know what am I missing here?